# Will the "Intelligent Pet Patch 0.1.2" affect saved games?

Tags: nethack

I was curious as to why my dragons never use their breath attacks, and found the wiki says that pets never use ranged attacks (which explains a lot of deaths, both theirs and mine). It also had a link for the aforementioned "Intelligent Pet Patch 0.1.2" (link is on PET page of wiki). It sounds like a good addition, but I'm wondering if and how it will affect my saved games ( I've "parked" a few before taking on Rodney).  What can I expect if I add this patch?